# How to show list brand filter/link on woocommerce base on product categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

i want to show list brand filter base on categories. say that we have 2 categories such as Television and Shoes. if we are at page Television show list brand LG and Samsung, but when we are at page Shoes show list brand Niki and Adidas? How to make it Happen?

i'm using WooCommerce Brands plugin.

See this link:
https://woocommerce.com/products/brands/
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/wc-brands

Thanks

Comment: you know product brand on woocommerce?

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/wc-brands/

you right, so i'm asking here how to make it happen?

Comment: You should edit your question adding that you are using WooCommerce Brands plugin with the link, as this detail is very important, if you want to get some chances that people will make an answer…

Comment: Ok Thanks for your suggestion